# how to play youtube videos while lock the screen?

Tags: ios, objective-c, youtube-api, background-process

I am trying to play youtube videos in my ios app while lock the screen. I have completed to play the videos while lock the screen but I want display progress bar and image of video(lock the screen).like this image

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVIOV.png

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik you can find image here
http://i.stack.imgur.com/SVIOV.png

Comment: @Paulw11 ..sry i.e not possiable?

Comment: That's right. An app cannot display anything on the lock screen.

Comment: @Paulw11  .already i have done  palying videos while lock the screen with image .... but i want also show the progress bar

Comment: That's what I meant, you can't add app controls to the lock screen.  Your app isn't showing the video, the AV framework is (I realise this is just semantics) but there isn't the ability to add arbitrary controls to the lock screen, only what is supported by iOS frameworks

Comment: yes it is palying by audio while lock the screen.